# Dropwizar doesn't see method marked with @Timed annotation if it is invoked by sheduled job

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, dropwizard

I have job:

```
public class Jobber {
    @Timed(name = "my_timed")
    public void someJob(String symbol) {
        LOGGER.info("Started job");
        ...
    }
   public void startJob(String currency){
       threadPoolTaskScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                () -> {
                  someJob(currency);                            
                }
                }, 5_000);

    }
```

and starter:

```
public class AppEvenListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
    @Autowired
    private Jobber jobber;



    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        jobber.startJob("USD");

    }
}
```

And then I started application and see that dropwizard doesn't saw that metric "my_timed"  is empty:

```
count = 0
     mean rate = 0.00 calls/second
 1-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
 5-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
15-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
           min = 0.00 milliseconds
           max = 0.00 milliseconds
          mean = 0.00 milliseconds
        stddev = 0.00 milliseconds
        median = 0.00 milliseconds
          75% <= 0.00 milliseconds
          95% <= 0.00 milliseconds
          98% <= 0.00 milliseconds
          99% <= 0.00 milliseconds
        99.9% <= 0.00 milliseconds
```

It was surprising for me because of I was able to find a lot of `Started job` messages in logs.

Then I tried to do smt like this inside `main` method:

```
 Jobber jobber = applicationContext.getBean(Jobber.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
jobber            jobber.someJob("Ololo");
            Thread.sleep(10_000);
        }
```

And after it I started to see not empty metrics for "my_timed"

So I believe issue somehow related to background threads.

how can I fix it?

**P.S.** Spring boot version = 1.5

Comment: `@Timed` is just a trigger for AOP (like `@Transactional`). Spring uses proxies to implement AOP, and thus internal method calls don't work. Internal method calls don't pass thorugh the proxy and thus don't get intercepted.

Comment: @M. Deinum, any workaround possible for my case?

Comment: You already have the workaround. Call the `@Timed` method from an external class.

Comment: @M. Deinum but ut is code uglyfication

Comment: Then don't use proxies but fullblown AspectJ to to loadtime or compile timeweaving (which is harder to setup and work with!). This is the drawback of using proxies and is an issue with each framework that uses proxies (it stems from the EJB legacy which started to do that).